# “Remote command failed with exit status 127”

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, ant

### I have a batch file as below:

```
@echo off

REM <--Fetching installed service pack version and storing it in var-->
FOR /f "tokens=* " %%a in ('findstr /I "install.servicepack" ^< "C:\A\B\C\D.properties" ') DO SET temp=%%a
SET var=%temp:~22%
REM <-- I tested, correct value is getting assigned to var say 1.2.3-->

REM <--Next, I am changing the directory using CD, in which X, Y and Z is a fixed directory path and after that it is variable based upon %var% value

cd c:\X\Y\Z\%var%
echo %cd%
REM <-- I tested and directory is correctly set against cd c:\X\Y\Z\1.2.3

REM <--With in c:\X\Y\Z\%var% (c:\X\Y\Z\1.2.3), there is an exe called uninstaller.exe and I am executing it is below:
dir
ECHO MESSAGE: Starting Silent Uninstallation of ABC Package
uninstaller.exe -options -silent
ECHO MESSAGE: Finished Silent Uninstallation of ABC Package
```

---

**Set-up**: I have Jenkins installed on windows and via sshexec task in ANT, I am calling the above batch file in a remote windows machine using cygwin openssh.

**Issue**: The above script when called from Jenkins job using above set-up, it is returning “Remote command failed with exit status 127”. However, if I am hard coding the value of %var% in cd as cd c:\X\Y\Z\a.b.c rather than passing as cd c:\X\Y\Z\%var%, script is executing fine, i.e.; directly changing the directory with the exact path (cd C:\X.Y.Z.\1.2.3).

I tried couple of ways to call uninstaller.exe after changing the directory but no success.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do NOT change value of `TEMP` variable: this is a special system variable holding the temporary directory env. variable.

Please choose another variable name.

```
FOR /f "tokens=* " %%a in ('findstr /I "install.servicepack" ^< "C:\A\B\C\D.properties" ') DO SET t=%%a
SET var=%t:~22%
```

If you change temporary directory, programs relying on it may crash (and there are a lot of them).